# How Can I change a string to the UTF-8 format in android

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8

How Can I change a string to the UTF-8 format in android? For example when I get a text string from server I want change the text format to the UTF-8. How can I do this?

```
String getText = text; // this text variable has a value from the server and now I want change it to UTF-8 format.
```

Answer (score 1):

`String` objects hold UTF-16 data internally.  If what you want is to encode a `String` as UTF-8 for exporting, you need to convert it to a UTF-8 encoded `byte[]` array, such as with the [`String.getBytes(Charset charset)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)) or  [`String.getBytes(String charsetName)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.lang.String)) method, eg:

```
byte[] byteArray = text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

```
byte[] byteArray = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Answer (score -2):

Hi You could use the String constructor with the charset parameter:

```
try
{
    final String s = new String("AnyStringThatYouwant to convert", "UTF-8");
}
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
{
    Log.e("utf8", "conversion", e);
}
```

Comment: There is no such `String` constructor.  All of the constructors that accept a charset as input expect a `byte[]` array as input.  A `String` holds only UTF-16 data, so the constructor interprets the `byte[]` data in the specified charset so it can be decoded to UTF-16.  That is not what the OP is asking for.